# Expansion of logarithm with little o

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Prove that
$$
\ln (1+z+o(z))=z-\frac{z^{2}}{2}+o\left(z^{2}\right), \quad z \rightarrow 0.
$$
My attempt is to use Taylor's expansion, so we get
$$\ln (1+z+o(z))=z+o(z)+o(|z+o(z)|^2).$$ What are further steps?

Comment: The exercise is incorrect (but is potentially correct if they intended Big-Os in some places, rather than Little-Os)

Answer (score 1):

You were too aggressive with your $o$s, and confused an $O(|z+o(z)|^2)$ term with $o(|z+o(z)|^2)$. You could have instead expanded as: $$z+o(z)-\frac{1}{2}(z+o(z))^2+o(|z+o(z)|^2)$$

We can clean this up as: $$z-\frac{1}{2}z^2+o(z)\quad(+o(z^2))$$But the power is $z^1$, not $z^2$, inside the $o$, so the original exercise was incorrect. A simple counterexample:

> Consider $f(z)=z^2\in o(z)$ as $z\to0$. The claim made by the exercise is that: $$\ln(1+z+f(z))-\left(z-\frac{1}{2}z^2\right)\in o(z^2)$$But I claim that this is false. $$\begin{align}\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\ln(1+z+f(z))-z+\frac{1}{2}z^2}{z^2}&=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\frac{1+2z}{1+z+z^2}-1+z}{2z}\\&=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\frac{z-z^2}{1+z+z^2}+z}{2z}\\&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to0}\frac{1-z}{1+z+z^2}\\&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\\&=1\\&\neq0\end{align}$$The first step substituted $f(z)=z^2$ and used De L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

When you have on $o(z)$ in a development it means that anything smaller than order $z$ is simply ignored.

When $z\to 0$ we have to ignore any terms in $z^a$ where $a>1$, in particular $z^2$ and of course even smaller terms like $o(z^2)$.

This means that the expansion requested is only $$\ln(1+z+o(z))=z+o(z)$$

Would you have $\ln(1+z+o(z^2))$ you would now be authorized to have terms in $z^2$ order and could carry the expansion further.

Here is another example:

Which terms to keep in the development of $\Big(a+bz+cz^2+o(z^2)\Big)^2$ ?

First the squares : $\require{cancel}a^2+b^2z^2+\cancel{c^2z^4}+\cancel{o(z^4)}$

Double products with a : $\require{cancel}2abz+2acz^2+o(z^2)$

Double products with bz : $\require{cancel}\cancel{2bcz^3}+\cancel{o(z^3)}$

Double products with cz^2 : $\require{cancel}\cancel{o(z^4)}$

The larger little o after developing everything is $o(z^2)$ so we ignore anything below $z^2$.

> In the end: $\Big(a+bz+cz^2+o(z^2)\Big)^2=a^2+2abz+(b^2+2ac)z^2+o(z^2)$

Would you have $o(z^3)$ inside the big parenthesis, you would be authorized to keep the additional term $2bcz^3$.

But what would be $\Big(bz+cz^2+o(z^2)\Big)^2$ ?

A trick to remember is to write $o(z^2)=\varepsilon z^2$ (little abuse of notation as we should write $\varepsilon(z)$ a function, but this is for comprehension purpose).

$\Big(bz+cz^2+\varepsilon z^2\Big)^2=b^2z^2+c^2z^4+\varepsilon^2z^4+2bcz^3+2b\varepsilon z^3+2b\varepsilon z^4$

You can see that the dominant term among the espilons is $\varepsilon z^3$, so we will carry the development up to $o(z^3)$

> $\Big(bz+cz^2+o(z^2)\Big)^2=b^2z^2+2bcz^3+o(z^3)$

A better way to do it is to factor $z$ out:

$\Big(bz+cz^2+o(z^2)\Big)^2=z^2\Big(b+cz+o(z)\Big)^2=z^2\Big(b^2+2bcz+o(z)\Big)=b^2z^2++2bcz^3+o(z^3)$

which is much more in line with "let ignore everything smaller than the little o inside the parenthesis".

---

Some rules with little o: (assuming $z\to 0$)

- $cst\times o(z^n)=o(z^n)$
- $z^no(z^p)=o(z^{n+p})=o(z^n)o(z^p)$
- $o(z^n)+o(z^p)=o(z^n)$ is $p\ge n$
- $o(z^n)^p=o(z^{np})$

You can generalize to $b=o(a)$ then $a+b+o(a)=a+o(a)$ and also $o(a+b)=o(a)$ i.e get rid of the negligible term.

In particular $o(|z+o(z)|^2)=o(z^2)$